# Deselect a Table View Cell that has been selected programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing a search feature where you can select results and I'm trying to make it so that it remembers which cells were selected if they show up in the results again.

I'm using `cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)` in the `willDisplayCell` function. However, now there is no way to deselect the cells. When tapped on again, neither the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` nor the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` functions are being called. What can I do?

Comment: Use this "cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)"

Comment: Yes, but where can I do this? None of the functions are being called when the cell is tapped. Which function can I use?

Comment: When you will tap a cell "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" should call. Check whether you set tableView delegate or not.

Comment: Nope, does not call if I set cell selected as I described above. However, it does call when I tap a cell that is unselected already.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath?NSIndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition)` to select cells. Then you'll get deselect events.

Comment: What if I don't have their index paths though? I'm using a property of the cell to identify which it is.

Comment: @JohnFda The index paths come from your data. If you dislike this solution, try to override `selected` in table view cell. Like this: `    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            
        }
    }
`